# Simplify an equation with Maple

Tags: maple

I am haunted by an equation which I could simplify it with hand and it equals to $-i$ (complexe number). But, I don't know how to use maplesoft to simplify it. The equation takes the form of:

```
-Omega*a*sqrt(2)*sqrt(-Omega^2*a^2-2*k*m+sqrt(Omega^2*a^2*(Omega^2*a^2+4*k*m)))/(-Omega^2*a^2+sqrt(Omega^2*a^2*(Omega^2*a^2+4*k*m)))
```

$-{\frac {\Omega\,a\sqrt {2}\sqrt {-{\Omega}^{2}{a}^{2}-2\,km+\sqrt {{
\Omega}^{2}{a}^{2} \left( {\Omega}^{2}{a}^{2}+4\,km \right) }}}{-{
\Omega}^{2}{a}^{2}+\sqrt {{\Omega}^{2}{a}^{2} \left( {\Omega}^{2}{a}^{
2}+4\,km \right) }}}
$

Thank you in advance for taking a look.  I'am sorry for not clarifying that the $a$ , $k$, $\Omega$ and $m$ are positive variables.

Comment: That expression doesn't simplify to $-i$ if, for instance, $a = 0$ (in which case the expression is an undefined quantity $0/0$, while $-i$ is not). I don't know how to tell Maplesoft that $a$ and $\Omega$ are nonzero, but without that information, a good algebra software tool isn't going to be able to get anywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'am sorry for not clarifying that the $a$ , $k$, $\Omega$ and $m$ are positive variables. I will try to tell Maplesoft the variables are nonzero.

Comment: I think that you can use [assuming](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=assuming)